# Getting an error when I run a V().has() gremlin query against IBM Graph service on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3, ibm-graph

I created an instance of IBM Graph service on bluemix and created some vertexes. When I try to issue a gremlin query to find one of the vertexes I created, I get an "Internal Error".

Here's the query I'm using

**Create the Vertex**
curl  -u  username-password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "label":"movie","properties":{"Name": "Million Dollar Baby","Type": "Movie"} }' -X POST "http://../g/vertices"

**Reponse**
{"requestId":"07f29cea-25b3-4305-b74b-540466206872","status":{"message":"","code":200,"attributes":{}},"result":{"data":[{**"id":8336**,"label":"movie","type":"vertex","properties":**{"Type":[{"id":"36a-6fk-1l1","value":"Movie"}**],"Name":[{"id":"2s2-6fk-sl","value":"Million Dollar Baby"}]}}],"meta":{}}}

**Query whether the vertex has a Type property 'movie'**
curl  -u  username-password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"gremlin": "def g = graph.traversal(); g.V().has('Type','movie')"}' -X POST "http://../g/gremlin"

**Response (Error)**
{"code":"InternalError","message":""}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IBM Graph requires users to create indexes for any property that they are going to issue queries against. In this case 'Type' is a property and is included in a gremlin query.

You need to create an index using the /schema endpoint which is provided by the IBM Graph service in bluemix.

An example of this is provided in the Service Getting Started guide
http://ibm-graph-docs.ng.bluemix.net/gettingstarted.html